# Из Visual Studio не создается бд FireBird

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, firebird

Не получается из VS подключиться к бд

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Test" connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=db.fdb;DataSource=localhost; port = 3050; Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime = 15; Pooling=false;Packet Size = 8192; ServerType=1;" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

По идее, при запуске файл с бд должен автоматически создаться, но сразу же вылетает ошибка

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: "An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure."

Создаю файл бд в ручную, тоже ошибка.
Пробую подключиться к этому файлу с помощью IBExpert, по данным, которые в строке подключения прописаны - все хорошо, все подключается.
Не могу понять почему из студии не получается подключение? 
Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с таким? 
Спасибо

Comment: _See the inner exception_ - смотрели? | _Создаю файл бд вручную, тоже оошибка_ - как именно вручную? какая ошибка? | _Пробую подключиться к файлу с IBExpert - все хорошо_ - так файл уже существует?

Comment: `ServerType=1` означает, что вы подключаетесь в embedded-режиме, в папке на выходе есть gds32.dll?

Answer (score 0):

По моему ругается на "Role=" в строке подключения, попробуйте без него.

Comment: Почему Вы так решили?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, есть ли клиентская библиотека gds32.dll в System32. Может быть ваш IBExpert использует дллку с другим именем или в другом каталоге.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было версию платформы на 86 поставить и все работает